# feeding divs from json

Tags: jquery

I am trying to feed 2 divs, `.totalmembers` and `.totalcomm` from a json file every 60 seconds.

json file looks like this, `{ "members": { "data": [ { "TotalMembers": 14 } ] }, "communities": { "data": [ { "TotalCommunities": 10 } ] } }`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    $(function FeedTicker() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "default.cs.asp?Process=ViewStats",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (index == "members") {
                    $(".totalmembers").html(data.totalmembers);

                } else if (index == "communities") {
                    $(".totalcomm").html(data.totalcommunities);
                }
            $('.totalmembers').ajaxSuccess(function(){
                $(this).ticker({
                    pauseOnItems: 6000, 
                    displayType: 'fade',
                    controls: false, 
                    titleText: ''
                });
            })
            $('.totalcomm').ajaxSuccess(function(){
                $(this).ticker({
                    pauseOnItems: 6000, 
                    displayType: 'fade',
                    controls: false, 
                    titleText: ''
                });
            })
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Posted is not a valid json?

Comment: I dont get an error but I dont get the data loaded to `.totalmembers` and `.totalcomm` either

Comment: The posted JSON does indeed not look like valid JSON, but if that is just a bit mangled from posting it here. Try data.members.data[1] to get to the totalmembers value...

Comment: Its a valid json, no problem there. I tried `$(".totalmembers").html(data.members.data[1]);`, it didnt work

Comment: @Efe I modified my answer below to show you how to get it working without modifying the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to modify your JSON. Something like `{ totalmembers: 109, totalcommunities : 3}`. That is what it would have to look like if you wanted it to work without modifying your JS.

Another option is to modify your JS. Change your success callback to:

```
function(data) {
  if (index == "members") {
    $(".totalmembers").html(data.members.data[0].TotalMembers);
  } else if (index == "communities") {
    $(".totalcomm").html(data.communities.data[0].TotalCommunities);
  }
}
```

I think it might also be a good idea to move your ajaxSuccess registrations to somewhere outside of your success callback. Currently your code is re-registering the divs every time an ajax request is successful.

Answer (score 0):

`data.totalmembers` And `data.totalcommunities` are may be the `List<something>` ?

If yes then you have to generate the HTML formation to feed the div

i.e. : data.totalmembers

foreach member in toatalmebers

`<table><tr><td>` totalmembers.name `</td></tr></table>....`

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying here

Comment: I mean to say that `totalmembers` and `totalcommunities` are not the string s that can be directly feed to div.
You have to create the html string containing the tags, and that string will be feeded to the div.